# ¿Cómo puedo renombrar una rama en Git?

Tags: git, ramas-git

Resulta que estoy trabajando en una rama de Git llamada `feature-bla` pero me doy cuenta que realmente debería llamarse `hotfix-bla`.

Sé que podría eliminar la rama y crear una nueva, pero se me ocurre que seguramente existe alguna manera de cambiar el nombre y así no perder commits ni nada.

¿Cómo puedo renombrar una rama en Git?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6591213/1983854

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si quieres renombrar una rama independientemente de la rama donde estés, utiliza:

```
git branch -m <nombre_viejo> <nombre_nuevo>
```

Si quieres renombrar la rama en la que estás actualmente, utiliza:

```
git branch -m <nombre_nuevo>
```

Donde `-m` puedes pensarlo como que es el comando "move".

En este caso, pues, debería decir `git branch -m hotfix-bla` o `git branch -m feature-bla hotfix-bla`.

<sub>Respuesta basada en la versión inglesa en [How do I rename a local Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/1983854)</sub>